# Negative Mutual information python

Tags: python, mutual-information

I calculated mutual information with the [PyInform function](https://elife-asu.github.io/PyInform/timeseries.html#module-pyinform.mutualinfo) with

> local = True
>
> MI = mutual_info(xs, ys, local=True)

In blue you see MI between the yellow and green line.
[image]

Can anyone tell me why MI goes into the negative?
Should I set the negative values to zero or do you think made an error somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative values are correct results.
Due to setting `local = True` the function is calculating the [pointwise mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) (referred to as *local mutual information* in the documentation).
The pointwise mutual information can take positive as well as negative values.
You can also see this in the example output given in the documentation you linked to:

```
>>> xs = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
>>> ys = [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
>>> mutual_info(xs, ys)
0.21417094500762912
>>> mutual_info(xs, ys, local=True)
array([-1.        , -1.        ,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,
        0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,
        0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,  0.22239242,
        0.22239242,  1.5849625 ,  1.5849625 ,  1.5849625 , -1.5849625 ])
```